# Bootstrap4 make card headers the same height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4's pricing template as an example, suppose I have card headers of different text length such that under some screen resolution the height of the card headers become different. I want to ensure that they are always of the same height.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">This is a really long header that is going to cause problem.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>10 users included</li>
          <li>2 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>20 users included</li>
          <li>10 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Priority email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>30 users included</li>
          <li>15 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Phone and email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The only way I can make this work is to do something like

```
.card-header{height: 50px;}
```

In CSS but this does not allow dynamic resizing. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/wshinigamic/pen/Jvedjq).

Comment: if it have a fixed height, you can hide overflow content (overflow: hidden;) or limit the characters with back-end  code

Comment: unfortunately there is no fixed height. I need to have same height based on the biggest card-header-height.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Bootstrap-4, use these classes  for the cards' header.

1. **`d-flex`** - to change its display to `flex`
2. **`align-items-center`** - center its content vertically
3. **`justify-content-center`** - center its content horizontally
4. **`h-100`** - to make its height `100%`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal flex-grow-1">This is a really long header that is going to cause problem. You can add more and more words but height will be the same! This is a really long header that is going to cause problem. You can add more and more words but height will be the same!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>10 users included</li>
          <li>2 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal flex-grow-1 ">Pro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>20 users included</li>
          <li>10 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Priority email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I recommend you use  the latest version of bootstrap and check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYQNmm)

---

## Update

If one of the cards has less content in its body, its header has more height. Add these classes to all the card bodies to fix the issue.

1. **`flex-column`** - to change its `flex-direction` to column
2. **`h-100`** - to make its height `100%`

```html
<div class="card-body flex-column h-100">
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal flex-grow-1">This is a really long header that is going to cause problem. You can add more and more words but height will be the same! This is a really long header that is going to cause problem. You can add more and more words but height will be the same!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body flex-column h-100">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>10 users included</li>
          <li>2 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
            <li>2 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal flex-grow-1 ">Pro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body flex-column h-100">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>20 users included</li>
          <li>10 GB of storage</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjQJBw)

Comment: Thanks! However, if one of the card has say 1 or 2 lesser list items, then the header would not be aligned anymore.

Comment: Try to do the same thing with the card-body too.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow this seems to only work on chrome. I have accepted this answer nonetheless since it is the closest to what I want to achieve. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one solution is using `text-overflow` property. in bootstrap, you can use `.text-truncate` class. it truncates your header text.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text text-truncate" title="This is a really long header that is going to cause problem.">This is a really long header that is going to cause problem.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>10 users included</li>
          <li>2 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text-truncate">Pro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>20 users included</li>
          <li>10 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Priority email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text-truncate">Enterprise</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>30 users included</li>
          <li>15 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Phone and email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

you can also give `title` attribute to your `h1` and set header text to it so user can show full text on hover

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add flex property to achieve that. Here is the example:

```
.card-header{
    display: flex;             
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
  h4{
    flex: 1;
  }
```

Here is the [Pen](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/vRPOKW)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately what this does seems to be pushing all the body content down and expands the header to fill up the space, so they are not the same height too.

Answer (score 1):

This may be late, but, hopefully it helps. I had a similar issue and I solved it by adding '`&nbsp;`' fillers to make the shorter header relatively the same length as the others and it appears to have worked. The header height now appears the same across every screen size, though I am using only the 'card-header' class in the card headers.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late too, but, hopefully it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = 0;
  $(".card-deck .card-header, .card-deck .card-footer").each(function(id, it) {
    if ($(it).height() > x) {
      x = $(it).height();
    }
  }).height(x);
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/felinuxltda/pen/KKVVYYN)