# Bootstrap4 : CardDeck + Card : How to get same height?

Tags: bootstrap-4, header, height, card

I tried to follow the question + answers from this question : [Bootstrap4 make card headers the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386953/bootstrap4-make-card-headers-the-same-height), however I cannot get it to work.

My html code is like:

```html
<div class="card-deck">
   <div class="card m-xs-1 m-2" style="">
      <div class="card-header" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat viverra odio pharetra lacinia.
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat viverra odio pharetra lacinia. Vestibulum mattis eros velit, hendrerit malesuada est hendrerit eget. Pellentesque urna quam, eleifend ut accumsan vel, feugiat et arcu. Curabitur consectetur tincidunt arcu, id sollicitudin erat egestas non
         </div>
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            <br>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-muted text-left" style="">
            <small>text</small>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card m-xs-1 m-2" style="">
      <div class="card-header" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat viverra odio pharetra lacinia. Vestibulum mattis eros velit, hendrerit malesuada est hendrerit eget. Pellentesque urna quam, eleifend ut accumsan vel, feugiat et arcu. Curabitur consectetur tincidunt arcu, id sollicitudin erat egestas non
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
         </div>
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            <br>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-muted text-left" style="">
            <small>text2</small>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this renders currently as:
[image]

## Update

When I the text in the second card has less characters, the code from the answer still renders not correct:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for your requirement:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="card-deck">
   <div class="card m-xs-1 m-2" style="">
      <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center h-100" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat viverra odio pharetra lacinia.
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center h-100" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat viverra odio pharetra lacinia. Vestibulum mattis eros velit, hendrerit malesuada est hendrerit eget. Pellentesque urna quam, eleifend ut accumsan vel, feugiat et arcu. Curabitur consectetur tincidunt arcu, id sollicitudin erat egestas non
         </div>
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            <br>
         </div>
       </div>
      <div class="card-footer" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-muted text-left" style="">
            <small>text</small>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card m-xs-1 m-2" style="">
      <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center h-100" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat viverra odio pharetra lacinia. Vestibulum mattis eros velit, hendrerit malesuada est hendrerit eget. Pellentesque urna quam, eleifend ut accumsan vel, feugiat et arcu. Curabitur consectetur tincidunt arcu, id sollicitudin erat egestas non
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center h-100" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
         </div>
         <div class="card-text text-left" style="">
            <br>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer" style="">
         <div class="card-text text-muted text-left" style="">
            <small>text2</small>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Currently I just use javascript to set the height of the headers.